# Unit test for methods with disposable

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a problem with unit testing.
I have a standart Reprository and UnitOfWork pattern. 
For example, I have a UnitOfWork class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    ... repositories 
    private IMyEntityRepository _myEntityRepository;
    ...
}
```

UnitOfWok used in another part of program witch make some special operations with entities. For example, there is a method, whitch use UnitOfWork:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> MyMethod()
  {
     using (_unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
     {
        var myEntities= _unitOfWork.MyEntityRepository.Get();

        var result = ... some logic to convert myEntities collection to IEnumerable<MyClass> 
        return result;
     }
  }
```

My question is how to write unit tests for MyMethod if there is consruction `using(_unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork)`? How could I use fake UnitOfWork with Fake context in that case? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: By not instantiating the context within the UoW class, but instead supplying it as a (constructor) dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your classes more fake-able and testable I would suggest abstracting your `UnitOfWork` and `Repositories` if possible and then use a factory to inject them into the classes that depend on them.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable {
    ... repositories 
    IMyEntityRepository MyEntityRepository;
    ...
}
```

And your `UnitOfWork` will derive from that interface

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {...}
```

**IUnitOfWorkFactory**

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory {
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}
```

With that, a dependent class can then look like this

```
public class MyDependentClass {
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory;

    public MyDependentClass (IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory) {
        this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> MyMethod() {
         using (var _unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory.Create()) {
             var myEntities= _unitOfWork.MyEntityRepository.Get();

             var result = ... some logic to convert myEntities collection to IEnumerable<MyClass> 
             return result;
         }
    }
}
```

Now you can mock/fake your `UnitOfWork` and `Repositories` with no need to fake the Context.

Lets say you want to test/verify that the UOW is actually disposed of after calling `MyMethod`

(I'm using `Moq` and `FluentAssert` for demonstrative purposes)

You can construct a test as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void UOW_Should_Be_Disposed() {
    //Assert
    var fake_entities = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new MyEntity());
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IMyEntityRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(fake_entities);
    var mockUOW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mockUOW.Setup(m => m.MyEntityRepository).Returns(mockRepository.Object);
    var mockFactory = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();
    mockFactory.Setup(m => m.Create()).Returns(mockUOW.Object);

    //Act
    var sut = new MyDependentClass(mockFactory.Object);
    var output = sut.MyMethod().ToList();

    //Assert
    output.Should().NotBeNull();
    output.Should().HaveCount(10);
    output.Should().ContainItemsAssignableTo<MyClass>();
    mockUOW.Verify(m => m.Dispose());
}
```

The above shows how you can test everything easily using the frameworks mentioned.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very mutch for detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject a factory of `UnitOfWork` into the class that contains the `MyMethod` method via constructor injection like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<UnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory;

    public MyClass(Func<UnitOfWork> unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> MyMethod()
    {
        using (unitOfWork = unitOfWorkFactory())
        {
            //..
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that the class takes a `Func<UnitOfWork>` instead of a `UnitOfWork` because I am assuming that you want each call to `MyMethod` to have a new instance of `UnitOfWork`.

In your tests, you create a fake `UnitOfWork` and then you can pass it to the `MyClass` instance like this:

```
var sut = new MyClass(() => fakeInstance);
```

You also need to make sure that `UnitOfWork` is fakeable. For example, since it is a concrete class, you need to make sure that the relevant methods are `virtual`. Another approach is to have an interface `IUnitOfWork` that `UnitOfWork` implements and that `MyClass` uses.